# JRuby on Rails and calendar_date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, jruby, production

Anyone have any success with a JRuby on Rails war deployment and calendar_date_select?  The gem wouldn't include the helper functions and I would receive the following error since the function wasn't declared in the app:

`undefined method 'calendar_date_select_includes' for #<ActionView::Base:0xbe823>`

After installing calendar_date_select as a plugin, I was able to get it to work in a war file deployment for the development environment.  Nevertheless, I'm now receiving the same error with the plugin when the rails environment in the war file is changed to 'production'.

any ideas on which direction to head?

JRuby: 1.3.0
Rails: 2.3.2
Calendar Date Select : 1.15
Tomcat: 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it using this patch: http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/issues/detail?id=161

It's because of `calendar_date_select` building a path for `/public` using `Rails.root` (which, when packaging the app with `Warble` is under `WEB-INF`).